# Generate unique ID to append records in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am using one postgreSql query which populates one table with some values and it takes different parameter when i run. I am appending rows each times i run the query with different parameter, Now i am interested in giving one auto generated ID to all rows which are coming as an output for one set of parameter.. So that I can access those rows which belong to certain parameters.

Can anyone help me how to append rows each time with one unique ID column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use serial (or bigserial for bigint) as column types.

They're in fact kind of *wrappers* over integer and biginteger types that *automagically* configures its default value to the `nextval()` of an ad-hoc *sequence* which it also creates for you under the hood.

To add such a field you only need to execute a sentence like this one below:

```
alter table your_table add column id serial primary key;
```

(Adjusting the table and column names to whatever you want/need).

> Obviously if you didn't yet created the table, you can simply add the field specifying it as `serial` in table declaration. But don't forget to also declare it as `primary key` to ensure it is treated as such.

This will create and fill in (because of its inherent default value) the column *id* with consecutive numbers in a single transaction.

Be aware that, depending on the table size it could take a considerable amount of time.

Also, for huge tables you may need to consider using *bigserial* instead of *serial*.

About getting the *id* assigned to a row you just inserted, you can add to the insert statement a `returning id` clause which will make it to act like a select returning a row (or multiple rows if inserting multiple ones with single statement) with it (of course you also can use `returning *` or `returning _whatever_columns_you_want_`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `RETURNING` statement to get returning ID

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (...) VALUES (...)
RETURNING idCol;
```

syntax

```
RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

Comment: This returning statement not working for me in postgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you want to keep track of a "runid" which is based on the parameter.  This would be a separate entity.  I would suggest a data structure like this:

```
create table runs (
    runid serial primary key,
    parameter varchar(255),
    createdAt timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

Then you would include `runid` in your table, with a foreign key reference to `runs`.

Finally you can insert into your table by doing:

```
with r as (
      insert into runs (v_parameter)
          values (parameter)
          returning *
     )
insert into yourtable ( . . . , runid)
    select . . ., r.runid
    from . . . cross join
         r;
```